# Error 404 when I tried to access my website

Tags: github, web, github-pages

Recently I tried to make a website using HTML and CSS and then I tried to host it on GitHub by commit under a repository name `myname_examp.github.io`, but when I tried to access it through the web browser using `myname_examp.github.io` there was an error 404.

Is there some steps to do?

Answer (score 1):

If your Github account is free tire, the Github pages repo **must be public**.

If you are using GitHub Enterprise Cloud and has access control, the site can only be accessed by people with read access to the repository where the site is published from.

You can use actions status to check whether your site ready:
[image]

See more on [Github docs](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/creating-a-github-pages-site)

BTW, if your site is project type (repo not named `user/org.github.io`), you shall go to repo setting enable pages.